# Writing to popen and reading back several files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, io, pipe

I need to run some shell commands on a number of files and sometimes I get back more than one file in response. The question is: *How can I read back several files from IO.popen in Ruby?*

For instance, imagine the following case:

```
file = grid.get(record['_id']) # fetch a file from database
IO.popen('tar -Oxmz', 'ab') {|pipe| pipe.write(file.read)} # pass to tar and extract
```

This necessitates that I reread all the extracted files from the filesystem. I figured out this is the speed bottleneck of my script and I wonder if I can accomplish the same task in-memroy. I tried the following:

```
file = grid.get(record['_id']) 
IO.popen('tar -Oxmz', 'w+b') do |pipe| 
   pipe.write(file.read)
   pipe.close_write
   output = pipe.read
end
```

It works, but I get the whole response, here including several extracted files, in one piece (in variable `output`). I need the files separate from each other and possibly with their names. Is there any way to do this?

By the way, the resulting files are most of the time text, but sometimes binary. Running a pipe for each output file is not a solution, because the actual overhead of running the commands for each file outweights the benefits of doing the transformation in-memory.

P.S. The actual use case does not rely on tar only. I use software that do not have Ruby wrappers.

Comment: I've been playing with this and I couldn't find any alternative to open a pipe for each file so... :/

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I wonder where all the EOF markers go...

Comment: I'm not an expert in unix but it seems that tar outputs everything at the same time.

Comment: Have you looked into --to-command ?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu Yes but it doesn't really solve the problem. For this specific use case I think I will end up creating a ram drive and extracting everything into it. This will render all the pain of piping unnecessary. I will also have a look at proper `pipe`s in Ruby IO and will report back if I find anything interesting.

Comment: Not a bad idea but the system should already cache the last accessed files  on memory so it might not help that much.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I agree. That's what I am trying to test.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I am done coding. Ram drive is way faster than the system's automatic file system caching. I totally recommend this solution, specially if you are in a Mac. Making a ram drive is only one line of code...

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for reporting back. Just curious, how mutch faster is it?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I haven't run proper tests, so I won't guesstimate. But a task that was at 30% and counting after two days, now is almost done overnight. The main culprits are compressed files whose content takes more than 100 MBs when expanded, and then some more when processed. I didn't even know I had such files.